# Flutter 2.0 User taps on Inkwell are not registered

Tags: flutter

I basically updated from flutter 1.22.6 to flutter 2.0, I am facing a very strange situation. Basically Inkwell does not register on taps unless I spam a button like 15 or 20 times with taps. I have no idea what is going on. Unless I downgrade to 1.22.6 this bug keeps occuring. Inkwell does not register on taps, as soon as finger is released(on pointer up event) it stops the ripple animation as if nothing happened, I can see the ripple animation with doing a long pointer down event and hold.

Is anyone facing the same issue right now?

I tried `flutter clean` and reinstalled the app but no, basically none of the buttons work beacause onTap of Inkwell is bugged.

Flutter Version:

```
> Flutter 2.0.0 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 60bd88df91
> (25 hours ago) • 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800 Engine • revision
> 40441def69 Tools • Dart 2.12.0
```

Comment: post your code then - i don see anything like that in my `InkWell`s

Comment: @pskink its the whole app that is broken, no gesture for on taps works unless I spam it 10 or 15 times, I can post an inkwell code but i dont think thats gonna help anyone, its simple plain inkwell

Comment: I solved my issue! `GestureBinding.instance.resamplingEnabled = true;` breaks Flutter 2.0, I think I found a major bug and will file an issue, I had that line under my main function, it is what is destroying onTaps. That line works fine in Flutter 1.22.6. I deleted that line and everything is working as usual.

Comment: Got lazy to fill an issue because they ask for lots of debug info and a new sample app didnt compile for me, if anyone is interested please file an issue over github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flutter 2.0 I think `GestureBinding.instance.resamplingEnabled` is broken, my app had this inside main function, I removed this line and it works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running

```
dart fix
```

in your project, that might do the trick

Comment: I get `Nothing to fix!`